# how to use sum and count (both) in mysql

Tags: mysql

my english is very poor.
my question is , how i can use sum and count in the same query ?

i have some like :

table "Febrero"

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| pregunta1 | pregunta2 | pregunta3 | pregunta4 | pregunta5 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 0         | 50        | 25        | 50        | 75        |
| 25        | 50        | 75        | 0         | 50        |
| 50        | 20        | 50        | 25        | 25        |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

and i try this.

```
select
       sum(pregunta1+pregunta2+pregunta3+pregunta4+pregunta5)/count(pregunta1),
       count(pregunta2),count(pregunta3),count(pregunta4),count(oregunta5) 
  from febrero;
```

i need = 570/15   ( total-sum/total-count ).

saludos.

Comment: What is the error that you receive when running the query?

Comment: One option: `select sum(pregunta1 + pregunta2 + pregunta3 + pregunta4 + pregunta5)/(5*count(*))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will produce what you want (also if table has NULL values):

```
select
  (sum(pregunta1)+sum(pregunta2)+sum(pregunta3)+sum(pregunta4)+sum(pregunta5)) /
  (count(pregunta1)+count(pregunta2)+count(pregunta3)+count(pregunta4)+count(oregunta5))
from febrero;
```